# Evaluating $\int_1^2 \int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}(x)\:\mathrm{d}y\:\mathrm{d}x$ using polar coordinates?

Tags: calculus, integration

How is the following integral found using polar coordinates.

$$\int_1^2 \int_{-\sqrt{4-x^2}}^{\sqrt{4-x^2}}(x)\:\mathrm{d}y\:\mathrm{d}x$$

I know the the part of the domain the circle being asked in r is from 1 to 2.

Then for theta it seems to be from $\frac{7\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{\pi}{4}$

So then I do

$\int_1^2 r\cos(\theta)(r) dr$

I get $\int r^2 \cos(\theta)$
then

$\frac{r^3}{3}\cos(\theta)$ plug in my my 2 and 1 and get.

$\int_{7\pi/4}^{\pi/4}\frac{7}{3}\cos(\theta)d\theta$

take my integration

I get

$\frac{7}{3}\sin(\theta)$ plug my numbers in and I get

$\frac{16\sqrt{2}}{6}$

but the correct answer is $2\sqrt{3}$

Comment: Always sketch the region in the $x-y$ plane over which you’re integrating. http://i.imgur.com/fBJxByZ.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:

Note that $-\frac{\pi}{3} \leq \theta \leq \frac{\pi}{3}$ and that for a given $\theta$ the range of $r$ is from $\frac{1}{\cos(\theta)}$ to $2$.

Therefore:
$$I = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \int_{\frac{1}{\cos (\theta)}}^2 r \cos (\theta)r \:\mathrm{d}r\:\mathrm{d}\theta \Rightarrow $$

$$I = \int_{-\frac{\pi}{3}}^{\frac{\pi}{3}} \int_{\frac{1}{\cos (\theta)}}^2 r^2  \:\mathrm{d}r \cos (\theta) \:\mathrm{d}\theta$$

Comment: I see so it is from 1/cos(theta) and not one

Comment: @FernandoMartinez Yes and the comment of Steve Kass is very useful to realize that.

Comment: The thing is I take the first integral I get $\frac{8}{3}cos(\theta)-sec^2(\theta)$

Comment: take the integral of that it is $\frac{8}{3}sin(\theta)-tan(\theta)$ and plug -pi/3 and pi/3 and I get $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$ and the correct answer is 2 square root(3)

Comment: @FernandoMartinez The first integral is $\frac{8}{3} \cos(\theta) - \frac{1}{3} \sec ^2 (\theta)$.

Comment: @FernandoMartinez And the second antiderivative is $\frac{8}{3} \sin(\theta) - \frac{1}{3} \tan (\theta)$.

Comment: Oh yes a foolish mistake on my part...

Comment: I see know ok thanks for  your help